# How to receive only the transactions about particular set of addresses from blockchain without full syncing?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, cryptocurrency

I am trying to parse Ethereum blockchain and read transactions which indicate transfer to or from the given set of addresses. The problem is that to do so full synced node is needed and it takes too much space on dist. So, is there any way (or software) to accept new blocks and just read transactions of my concern without downloading all other transactions and with the same safety checks of blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem of querying informations about a particular set of adresses, there are multiple ways to achieve that:

1. Use a blockchain explorer like https://aleth.io
2. Use Google Big Query (https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=ethereum_blockchain)
3. Use an archive synchronized node that unfortunately will fill up your hard drive!